# Probability of two independent events not occuring

Tags: probability, independence

Question - The probability that at least one of the two
independent events occurs is 0.5. The probability that the first event occurs but not the second is
3/25. Also, the probability that the second event occurs but not the first is 8/25. Find the
probability that none of the two events occurs.

Through this formula P(A'∩ B') = P(A'). P(B'), I am getting 0.5084, But if I complement P(AUB) which is given 0.5, It is obvious that is also 0.5. So, why am I getting different answers for two same things essentially?

Edit: If anyone is curious how I got 0.5084
P(A-B) = P(A) - P(A∩ B) -> 1
P(B-A) = P(B) - P(A∩ B) -> 2
P(AUB) = P(A)+P(B)-P(A∩ B) 
P(B) = 0.5 - 3/25 = 0.18 [from 1]
and similarly P(A) = 0.5-8/25 = 0.38
P(A'∩ B') = P(A'). P(B')
= 0.82*0.62 = 0.5048

Thank you so much to all of you and here I was banging my head in the wall thinking what am I doing wrong, I wasn't expecting the quick replies so thanks again and I think I would go with the 0.5.

Comment: I don't see the question here. If the probability of at least one event happening is 0.5, then the probability of no events happening is 1 - 0.5 = 0.5. I think the error arises from you getting wrong values of P(A') and P(B').

Comment: @JMoravitz I don't think that is the case. $\left( 1 - \frac 3{25} \right)\left( 1 - \frac 8{25} \right) = 0.5984$, not $0.5084$, unless OP made a mistake while inputting the question.

Comment: @OP By De Morgan's: $P(\bar{A}\cap \bar{B})=P(\overline{A \cup B})=1-P(A\cup B)=0.5$ so you're computing the probabilities wrong

Comment: I substituted these two in the union formula to find P(A) and P(B), P(A-B) = P(A) - P(A∩ B) and P(B-A) = P(B) - P(A∩ B)

Comment: Am I misreading something?  Let's let $p_A,p_B$ be the probabilities of the two events.  We can (almost) compute these since we are told that $p_A(1-p_B)=\frac 3{25}$ and $p_B(1-p_A)=\frac 8{25}$.  We deduce that the unordered pair $\{p_A,p_B\}$ is one of $\{\frac 15,\frac 25\}$ or $\{\frac 35,\frac 45\}$.  Either way, we get something other than $.5$ for the probability that at least one occurs.  Or have I miscalculated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that the problem statement gives contradictory information.  The probabilities given do not add up correctly.

You correctly found that $\Pr(A'\cap B')=1-\Pr(A\cup B)=1-0.5=0.5$ by DeMorgan's Laws.

You likely found that $\Pr(B') = \Pr(A'\cap B')+\Pr(A\cap B') = 0.5+\frac{3}{25}$ by the Law of Total Probability.

You similarly would have found that $\Pr(A')=\Pr(A'\cap B')+\Pr(A'\cap B) = 0.5+\frac{8}{25}$

You correctly found that if the events $A$ and $B$ *were* in fact independent then $A'$ and $B'$ would similarly be independent and that $\Pr(A'\cap B') = \Pr(A')\times\Pr(B')$ by definition of independence which would have required then that $(0.5+\frac{3}{25})\times(0.5+\frac{8}{25})=\Pr(A'\cap B')$ however this equaled $0.5084$ which does not match up with the $0.5$ we expected.

One of two things has likely gone wrong: The problem gave us incorrect numbers, perhaps due to rounding where not appropriate, for the values given in the problem... or they incorrectly told us that the events were independent when in fact they were not.

Comment: This is a problem from my maths assignment, so what should I do now?

Comment: Complain.  If no one is available to hear you complain just yet, then do as you had and show your work for both answers and point out in your answer that this gives contradictory information.  Expect an apology from whoever initially wrote and gave the question.

Comment: I would suggest you answer with 0.5, because that is the most obvious solution.

Comment: But as @JMoravitz points out, do complain first.

Comment: Yes, I will email them with the question attached.

Answer (score 0):

We are given $P(A \cup B) = 0.5, P(A \cap B') = 0.12$ and $P(A' \cap B) = 0.32$.

$P(A) = P(A \cup B) - P(A' \cap B) = 0.5 - 0.12 = 0.38$

$P(B) = P(A \cup B) - P(A \cap B') = 0.5 - 0.32 = 0.18$

Going by the formula, $P(A') = 0.62, P(B') = 0.82$ and $P(A' \cap B') = 0.62 \cdot 0.82 = 0.5084$. So both of your answers are correct. The question seems to be poorly constructed.

Answer (score 0):

Ther might be a mistake in the formulation: could it be that instead of "the probability that ***at least one of the two independent events occurs*** is 0.5" it should be "the probability that ***both of the two independent events occurs*** is 0.5"? If so, then the following approach solves your problem.

Fot two independent events $A$ and $B$ that might happen, there are only 4 possible outcomes of the experiment:

$$
\begin{aligned}
AB &= \text{"both }A\text{ and }B\text{ occur"} \\
\overline{A}B &= \text{"}A\text{ doesn't occur }\text{ and }B\text{ occurs"} \\
A\overline{B} &= \text{"}A\text{ occurs }\text{ and }B\text{ doesn't occur"} \\
\overline{A}\overline{B} &= \text{"neither }A\text{ no }B\text{ occur"} \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Then, we have that

$$
\begin{aligned}
P(AB + \overline{A}B + A\overline{B}+\overline{A}\overline{B}) &= P(AB) + P(\overline{A}B) + P(A\overline{B})+P(\overline{A}\overline{B}) = 1 \Rightarrow \\
\Rightarrow P(\overline{A}\overline{B}) &= 1 - P(AB) - P(\overline{A}B) - P(A\overline{B}) = \\
&= 1 - 0.5 - \frac{8}{25} - \frac{3}{25} = \frac{3}{50}. 
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: I think 3/50 is the intersection